# Select query with relationship laravel one to many

Tags: laravel

I have a relational mode like this:

**Model Siswa**

```
    public function kelengkapan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Modules\PesertaDidik\Entities\SiswaKelengkapan');
}
```

**Model SiswaKelengkapan**

```
 public function siswas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Modules\PesertaDidik\Entities\Siswa');
}
```

I want to use **select query with relational**

in this controller:

```
        $siswa = Siswa::select('nama', 'nisn', 'tempat_lahir', 'tanggal_lahir', 'jk')->with('kelengkapan')->get();
    return view('pesertadidik::crud.index', compact('siswa'));
```

this is my blade...

```
 <td>{{$data->kelengkapan->kelas_masuk}}</td>
```

but an error in the blade like this

```
Trying to get property 'kelas_masuk' of non-object
```

I want to show kelas_masuk in the table,

How to use the select query with relation eloquent?

Comment: please select primary key of table in select query

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your select query

You are trying to retrieve the data on null that's why you get `Trying to get property 'kelas_masuk' of non-object`

Controller

```
$siswa = Siswa::select('nama', 'nisn', 'tempat_lahir', 'tanggal_lahir', 'jk')->with('kelengkapan')->get();
return view('pesertadidik::crud.index', compact('siswa'));
```

Blade file

Assume you are using `foreach` or `forloop`

```
<td>{{ $data->kelengkapan->kelas_masuk ?? '--' }}</td> //coalescing operator

Or

<td>
  @if(!is_null($data->kelengkapan))
      {{ $data->kelengkapan->kelas_masuk }} 
  @endif
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you are used get() method so it's return all the rows

```
$siswa = Siswa::select('nama', 'nisn', 'tempat_lahir', 'tanggal_lahir', 'jk')->with('kelengkapan')->get();
return view('pesertadidik::crud.index', compact('siswa'));
```

in your blade

```
 <td>{{$siswa[0]->kelengkapan->kelas_masuk}}</td>
```

You can also use foreach loop.

```
@foreach($siswa as $data) 
<tr>
     <td>{{$data->kelengkapan->kelas_masuk}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Get method return `collection` not `array` until if you not used `pluck` or `toArray`. In blade file, you are trying to access `object` not an `array`